# R: Getting Wrong Profile Likelihood Confidence Interval Estimates

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, extreme-value, pareto-distribution, profile-likelihood

I am trying to estimate the profile likelihood confidence interval (CI) of the parameters ($\xi$, $\sigma$) of the Generalized Pareto Distribution (GPD). However, the lower estimate (left CI) of $\xi$ is greater than the point estimate and the upper estimate (right CI) is lesser than the point estimate which is impossible. My application, in which I used a different set of data, takes inspiration from the paper titled, "[An Application of Extreme Value Theory for Measuring Financial Risk](http://www.unige.ch/ses/dsec/static/gilli/evtrm/GilliKelleziCE.pdf)."

The code:

```r
    # The profile log-likelihood function
    profileloglikelihood.VaRp <- function(theta, VaRp, x){
      xi <- theta[1] # xi parameter
      u <- 0.015 # The treshold
      n <- length(log_returns) # The length of the data set 
                               # (7213 data point)
      p <- 0.01 # 0.99 confidence
      Nu <- length(x) # The number of observations (225 
                      # observations) above the threshold u 
      sigma <- ((xi*(VaRp - u))/(((n*p)/Nu)^(-xi) - 1)) 
      profL <- -Nu*log(sigma) - (1/xi + 1)*sum(log(1 + 
                 (xi/sigma)*x)) # The reparameterized 
                                # log-likelihood (see page 18)
      return(-profL)
    }

    VaRp.vec <- seq(0.02, 0.07, length.out=400) 
                       # A vector of VaR values 
    
    # Matrix containing xi values and their corresponding 
    # negative log-likelihood values
    VaRp.profile <- matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = length(VaRp.vec))
    colnames(VaRp.profile) = c("xi", "NLL")
    
    # The excesses over threshold
    x <- sort(log_returns)[(length(log_returns) - 225 + 
                1):length(log_returns)] - 0.015
    
    # The optimization routine
    for (i in seq_along(VaRp.vec)) {  
      res <- optim(fn = profileloglikelihood.VaRp, par = c(0.1), 
               VaRp = VaRp.vec[i], x = x, method = 'Brent', 
                 lower = -0.5, upper = 0.5)  
      VaRp.profile[i, ] = c(res$par, res$value)  
    }
```

The plot:

[image]

The point estimate of VaR is $0.0224318924777785$, which can be obtained through the code:

```r
    # See equation (10) at page 8
    GPDVaR <- function(xi, sigma, u, n, Nu, p){
      return(u + (sigma/xi)*(((n*p)/Nu)^(-xi) - 1))
    }

    GPDVaR(0.131949421307554, 0.00605472852770608, 0.015, 
               length(log_returns), 225, 0.01)
```

Now for the lower CI of VaR$_{0.01}$:

```r
    lowervalues <- c()
    for(i in 1:length(VaRp.vec)){
    if(VaRp.vec[i] < 0.0224318924777785 & (894.370814517731 - 
      1.92) > -profileloglikelihood.VaRp(unname(VaRp.profile[, 
                  c(1)][i]), 
    VaRp.vec[i], x)){
       lowervalues <- c(lowervalues, VaRp.vec[i])
    }
    }
    max(lowervalues)
```

I get $0.0212531328320802$. However, when I check the $\xi$ parameter corresponding to this lower confidence interval, which can be done as follows:

```r
    VaRp.profile[, c(1)][length(lowervalues)]
```

I get $0.204611486722261$ which is superior to the point estimate $0.131949421307554$. I've spent hours trying to figure out a solution to this but I failed. Can anyone point me to the error(s) I made for I would be really thankful.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but in the Bayesian world you can get credible intervals that don't include maximum posterior density estimates, which is why more statisticians are using highest posterior density intervals instead of credible intervals, the latter being computed in the same way as confidence intervals, just using the parameter distribution instead of the sample distribution.

Comment: Your question seems quite noisy. I understand that `VaRp` is the quantile with probability $1-p$ which is used with the shape $\xi$ to parameterize the GPD. So $p$ is *not* a confidence level.  You are finding a profile-likelihood interval on this quantile and `log_returns`  is the original sample before selecting the observations over the threshold `u`. The R function `profileloglikelihood`  is the log-likelihood (not the profile) and `theta` is `xi`.